# Why doesn't the method "printperson()" invoke the subclass's private method?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, private, public

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Person().printPerson();
     new Student().printPerson();
  }
}

class Student extends Person {
  private String getInfo() {
     return "Student";
  }
}

class Person {
  private String getInfo() {
    return "Person";
  }
  public void printPerson() {
    System.out.println(getInfo());
  }
}
```

The answer is

> Person
>   Person

But when I change both the private access-specifiers to public, the result is

> Person
>   Student

Why? I can't understand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is off-topic as it provides no information.  A link to a photograph of some code is insufficient, you must include the code in your post.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  StackOverflow is intended to benefit future readers not just answer your question.

Comment: First Go read java then you will find Your Answer @kangzhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private methods are not visible in subclasses and therefore can't be overriden. So it always invokes a method from parent class.